# comment for the given data (linear regression)

Tags: regression, linear

An actuary is asked to check a linear regression calculation performed by a trainee.
The trainee reports a least-squares slope parameter estimate of b
! = 13.7 and a sample
correlation coefficient r = –0.89.
(i) Justify why this suggests that the trainee has made an error.

Comment: Hint: look at the sign.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.